# How to plot (y vs x) a not invertible function say F(x,y)=const?

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematica, polylogarithm

I am trying to plot (y vs x) for a not invertible function PolyLogarithm[1.5,y/x]=const.
Any Ideas how to do this, say on Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot3D[PolyLog[1.5, y/x], {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}]

[image]

ContourPlot[PolyLog[1.5, y/x] == 2, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}]

[image]

Comment: I am trying to plot y vs x (2 D plot) which will be a line in the 3D plot you have shown.

Comment: Like the update?

Comment: Thnx :) This is what i was looking for. Link means?

Comment: Nice plots! TU!

Comment: @amWhy: Hope you are having a great day! Happy Saturday! :-) Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's been a nice day, thanks! Hope you're enjoying your weekend!